# Shortcode with form shows duplicate entry fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, shortcode

I created a search form for my custom post types and I want to be able to place it anywhere on my site, so I created a shortcode. The vanilla form works fine, but in a shortcode, it's displaying duplicate fields. Can anyone see why it would do this? The top 3 fields are duplicates of the fields in the lower form. You can see the result at http://autismva.teebark.com/resource-finder-3.

You can see the vanilla form at http://autismva.teebark.com/resource-finder2

```
function resource_search_form( $form ) {
$form = '<form id="category-select" class="category-select"  method="post" action="' . esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')) . '" >' .
    wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=1&hierarchical=1&depth=2&show_option_none=Select by category&name=$cat_id&taxonomy=resource_cat' ) . '<br>' .
    wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=0&hierarchical=1&depth=1&show_option_none=Select by age&name=$age_id&taxonomy=resource_age' ) . '<br>' .
    wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=0&exclude=128&show_option_none=Select by region&name=$region_id&taxonomy=resource_region' ) . '<br>' .
    '<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search by keyword" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="tag_name" placeholder="Search by tag" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="resource_search_cat2" />
    <button type="submit" > Search </button>
</form>';
return $form;
}

add_shortcode('resource_search', 'resource_search_form');

**The vanilla form:**
<form id="category-select" class="category-select"  method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" >
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=1&hierarchical=1&depth=2&show_option_none=Select by category&name=$cat_id&taxonomy=resource_cat' ); ?><br>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=0&hierarchical=1&depth=1&show_option_none=Select by age&name=$age_id&taxonomy=resource_age' ); ?><br>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=0&exclude=128&show_option_none=Select by region&name=$region_id&taxonomy=resource_region' ); ?><br>
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search by keyword" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="tag_name" placeholder="Search by tag" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="resource_search_cat2" />
    <button type="submit" > Search </button>
</form>
```

Comment: afaik you have to pass `echo=false` to `wp_dropdown_categories` when you use it within a shortcode. You want the function  to return the output, not display it.

Comment: Perfect--thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.
// write this action in your "after_setup_theme" hook

```
add_action( ' woocommerce_single_product_summary ' , ' your_function_name ' , 10 );

//define your function that contains the removal action hook.
function your_function_name()
{
   remove_action( ' woocommerce_single_product_summary ' , ' woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart ' , 30 );
}
```